# "We do me old" What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I don't understand the meaning of the interjection **we do me old** in this [article](https://www.miaminewtimes.com/arts/stanley-fishs-top-10-films-list-for-ny-times-is-perhaps-the-worst-ever-6493031). I can't find it on Google. Is it simply a typo for "*we do **mean** old*"?

> Florida International University professor and all around curmudgeon Stanley Fish is up to his old -- and **we do me old** -- tricks in the New York Times again.

Comment: Looks like a typo, if you ask me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typo.  The sentence should be "and we do mean **old**"

Answer (score 2):

It is a typo.

The article is stressing **old** and that the author of the NYT OpEd created a

> Good god, is it a curmudgeonly **old**-guy list.

So the phrase you are questioning should probably read

> Stanley Fish is up to his old -- and we do me**an** old -- tricks in the New York Times again